# How i can position my icons images in rows and columns with out having to use table

Tags: html, css

I have 5 icons images. and i want to position them as follow:-

[image]

and to guarantee consistent layout on all the screen sizes, i added a table without boarder and i position the icons inside the table cells as shown above.

But now i want to change the layout to be something as follow:-
[image]

where using tables will no longer work.. so can anyone adivce on which appraoch i can use to position my icons as shown in the second picture? and to guranteee that the images will always be shown in the desored layout even on small sized screens.. as i am adding the above html inside iframes on many web pages.

Regards

here is my markup for the table:-

```
<table class="ms-rteTable-0 " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 15%; height: 198px;">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px; height: 16px;">​<a title="" href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px; height: 59px;"/></a></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" style="width: 20px; height: 16px;">​<a title="" href="/" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px; height: 59px;"/></a></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px; height: 16px;">​<a title="" href="" target="_blank"><img src="" _moz_resizing="true" alt="" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px; height: 59px;"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" rowspan="1" style="width: 30px; height: 76px;">​<a title="" href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px; height: 59px;"/></a></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" rowspan="1" style="width: 20px; height: 76px;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" rowspan="1" style="width: 30px; height: 76px;">​<a title="" href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px; height: 59px;"/></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: flexbox/CSS grid/media query and so one ...

Comment: Do you need this to be responsive in any way, or do you just want the whole thing to cause scroll bars if there isn’t enough space for it?

Comment: What HTML are you working with? What was your best effort? Show us the [mcve] so that we can usefully help you. You've asked more than 900 questions, surely this isn't the first time you've been prompted to provide relevant information?

Comment: @CBroe if responsive can be done,, then it will be better

Comment: @DavidThomas i editted my question and i provided the markup.. soory i forget to include this

Comment: Don't get me wrong but i'm somehow surprised at 900 questions!! from the OP

Comment: If you can live with scroll bars - then put it into a container element with the necessary width and height explicitly specified. If you want it to be responsive - then go look into the basics of that topic first, this is rather too broad.

Comment: @cjmling do not worry.. if you check my questions,,, there are related to asp.net mvc + database + entity framework... but somethings i have to deal with some html and css stuffs which is not my expertise...

Comment: @CBroe i think scroll bars should be fine at this stage... so how i can use containers?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I tried your code and saw what it does. And what you want can be done using this :-
This is CSS code put it in   in the head tag

```
.icon {
 width: 60px;
 height: 59px;
}
```

This is the image part:- setting width and using overflow will prevent auto-wrapping.

```
<div style="width: 190px; overflow: hidden;">
      <img class='icon' src="">
      <img class='icon' src="">
      <img class='icon' src="">
   <div style="margin-top: 4ex; margin-left:4.5ex;">
      <img class='icon' src="">
      <img class='icon' src="">
   <div>
</div>
```

[Thats how it will look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JehXe.png)